# How do you ORDER BY a column when the CASE name is the same name as the column

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and am currently learning through Codecademy.

I'm doing a CASE statement query but I wanted to do a little extra by adding an ORDER BY.

The question is:

> Use a CASE statement to change the rating system to:
> review greater than 4.5 is Extraordinary,
> review greater than 4 is Excellent,
> review greater than 3 is Good,
> review greater than 2 is Fair,
> Everything else is Poor.
> Don’t forget to rename the new column!

The answer it gave me is:

```
SELECT name,
  CASE
    WHEN review > 4.5 THEN 'Extraordinary'
    WHEN review > 4 THEN 'Excellent'
    WHEN review > 3 THEN 'Good'
    WHEN review > 2 THEN 'Fair'
    ELSE 'Poor'
  END AS 'Review'
FROM nomnom;
```

What I'm trying to do is add an ORDER BY for the column 'review' but it's ordering by the new CASE column 'Review' instead. How do I specify I want the original column 'review' to be ordered? Or do I have to rename the CASE column name?

My attempt:

```
SELECT name AS 'Name',
  CASE
    WHEN review > 4.5 THEN 'Extraordinary'
    WHEN review > 4 THEN 'Excellent'
    WHEN review > 3 THEN 'Good'
    WHEN review > 2 THEN 'Fair'
    ELSE 'Poor'
  END AS 'Review'
FROM nomnom
ORDER BY review DESC;
```

This results in an ORDER BY for the CASE statement column 'Review' instead of the wanted table column 'review'

Any additional advice or comments are appreciated!

Comment: does `ORDER BY nomnom.review` work? Else as you suggested use a new alias such as `.. END AS ReviewLabel`

Comment: Don't 'quote' a derived column, simple use its name, or "delimit" it with double quotes or the delimiters used by your RDBMS if necessary; giving your column the same name as an existing column means you have to tell the query engine *which* one you mean - either prefix it with the table name or use an *alias*.

Comment: What error does `My attempt:` generate, or what result that is different from what you expect? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @Rippo adding the nomnom.review worked, thank you!

Comment: @AD7six It wasn't giving me an error. I did say what the result was giving me which wasn't exactly what I was looking for "but it's ordering by the new CASE column 'Review' instead"

Comment: I see you’ve edited your comment into the question - It’d be much more helpful to just show the result (or a representative snippet of it).

Comment: Without the example of what you are seeing this question doesn’t seem to make sense - as should be apparent from the accepted answer it’s unexpected to be able to sort by a derived column. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat the CASE expression in the ORDER BY clause, but with no name. I know it seems like a lot of code and bad DRY, but it's really just one copy/paste operation and there are a number of places in SQL where we unfortunately have to break the "don't repeat yourself" rule.

Or maybe I misunderstood, and you want to order by the column name. Then you can fully-qualify the column name (`ORDER BY nomnom.Review`)

Comment: Yes all I wanted was to order by the column name. Using nomnom.review worked, thank you!